# install Java library [GIThub source code] on android

Tags: java, android, github

I need to install a library from java with source on GIT [jawampa](https://github.com/Matthias247/jawampa)

Im not sure how to install in my android intelliJ project, I think I have to import jar, but where is the jar here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the github repo you provided gives information on how to add it as a maven dependency, so assuming you're using gradle (which is standard for new projects in Android Studio) you should just have to add

```
compile 'ws.wamp.jawampa:jawampa-core:0.4.0'
```

to the dependencies section of the build.gradle file under the app/ directory of your project.

FYI the library you refer to is on mvnrepository:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ws.wamp.jawampa/jawampa-core/0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

Add this as a dependency to your Gradle build file

```
  compile 'ws.wamp.jawampa:jawampa-core:0.4.0-STAGING'
```

You can get the latest dependency info for this project on [maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cws.wamp.jawampa)